# create single exe file from node app in linux

Tags: node.js

I'm developing a node express+ejs web app on ubuntu and I need to create single exe file from it with external /data folder that contains multiple sqlite and json files.

In app, excel files can be imported and then converted to sqlite database files (that's why I need an external data folder)

The exe file will execute from NAS device by network users in windows .

I installed pkg and make exe file but it's not working (nothing happened), no error no log. I expected to see opened browser because I use opn in onlisten event (it's working on development)

What should I do make it work?

Comment: Could you add your pkg config and the command you used for the build?

Comment: no additional config and "pkg -t win -o app.exe app.js"